# 1D Convolution in Neural Networks

Tags: conv-neural-network

I understand how convolution works but I don't get how 1D convolutions are applied to 2D data.

[image: 2D convolution]

In this example you can see a 2D convolution in a 2D data.
But how it would be if was a 1D convolution?
Just a 1D kernel sliding in the same way? And if the stride was 2?

Thank you!

Comment: Just look at the first row of each matrix.

Comment: Can you give me a example?

Comment: 1d convolutions wouldn't really be useful for a strict 2d image. Non-grayscale images are 3D technically since they have three color channels.

Comment: @Gustavo Like this one: http://toto-share.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/convolution_ilustration.png Unless you mean 1x1 convolution (in the sense of neural networks), which is a different thing.

Comment: My problem is with convolutions like: http://d3kbpzbmcynnmx.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Screen-Shot-2015-11-06-at-8.03.47-AM.png
 There are two convolutions, one with kernel size 3 and other with size 2...   But those kernel are 1D or size x k ?

Comment: Image source: http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Feature_extraction_using_convolution

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1, …,x_n $ be a sequence of vectors (e.g., word vectors). Applying a convolutional layer is equivalent to applying the same weight matrices to all n-grams, where $n$ is the height of your filter. E.g., if $n=3$, you can visualize it as follows:

[image]

For a slightly more mathematical explanation, you can check out 
*Ji Young Lee, Franck Dernoncourt. "[Sequential Short-Text Classification with Recurrent and Convolutional Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.03827)". NAACL 2016*. section 2.1.2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1D convolutions are used in convolutional networks for down sampling and up sampling in the filter dimension. Convolutional networks build up these filter maps as you go through the network, you can really think of them as a 3rd dimension. The usual base case of the filter map dimension is a size of 3, since we will often have RGB images going through our network.

These 1D convolutions can be useful for down sampling, performing some operation, then up sampling back to the same dimension. This is quite useful for performance reasons.

To really intuitively understand I'd suggest reading:

Network-in-network - http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.4400

Going deeper with convolutions - https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.cs.unc.edu/~wliu/papers/GoogLeNet.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwi89oeuxqnLAhXhuIMKHZrTCe0QFggkMAE&usg=AFQjCNGCEEnUgrgCn-rrECNQ72wI3PH1Qw&sig2=VhjfaMvuskNIDVKhFfNiqQ

Comment: It seams that you talk about 1x1 convolutions (in the sense of neural networks) rather than 1D convolutions.

Comment: Right, I assumed that neural networks were involved. I came across a link to this question on /r/MLQuestions on reddit so I assumed it was ML related. But for just plain convolution this isn't as relevant :P.